# Custom command in \NewDocumentCommand documentation

Tags: math-mode, macros, errors, xparse

I'm seeing a rather unexpected result with `\NewDocumentCommand`. Suppose I have a custom-defined command `\mybold{}`, like this:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\mybold}{m}{\mathbf{#1}}
```

Or `\oybold[]`:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\oybold}{O{a}}{\mathbf{#1}}
```

I would *expect* to be able to refer to these in another `\NewDocumentCommand`, like any of the following:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\mmyvec}{m}{\hat\mybold{#1}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\moyvec}{m}{\hat\oybold[#1]}
\NewDocumentCommand{\omyvec}{O{a}}{\hat\mybold{#1}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\ooyvec}{O{a}}{\hat\oybold[#1]}
```

The first and the third just produce a bunch of errors (`missing $ inserted`, `missing } inserted`, `extra }` etc.); while `\moyvec[k]` and `\ooyvec[k]` produce the following output:

[image]

(rather than the desired `\hat\mathbf{k}`)

I assume this has something to do with it entering math mode *twice*. How can I fix this?

Comment: do not show only code snippets. Always show a small but complete example that can be used for a test.

Comment: `\hat\mybold`  is the same as `\hat{\mybold}`  so naturally raises errors as the base of the accent is `\mybold` with no argument supplied.

Comment: This isn't related to math mode or `\NewDocumentCommand` you would see same if you defined `\mybold` simply as `\def\mybold#1{#1}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want the argument of `\hat` to be `\mybold{#1}`  not `\mybold` so the markup should be `\hat{\mybold{#1}}`

with the optional argument version it is similar `\hat{\oybold}[k]`  the base of the accent is `\oybold` with no optional argument so you get `\hat{a}` then the `[k]` is just typeset as text, it is not an argument to the command.

You want `\hat{\oybold[#1]}`